# REST API to list of Pricing Tier of Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any API management service to list out the available Pricing Plans for a SQL Database?

Available Plans:
1) P1 Premium 
2) P2 Premium
3) P4 Premium
4) P6 Premium
5) P11 Premium
6) S0 Standard
7) S1 Standard
8) S2 Standard
9) S3 Standard
10) B Basic

I want to get this list through REST API.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there's no REST API to programmatically fetch this information.

You could however make use of Billing and Usage API as mentioned by Steve in his comment but you will need to filter out the data first by meter category/sub category (`Data Services` and `SQL Database` respectively) and then pick the meter name for a single region where SQL Database is offered (e.g. US West).